# android : editing images

Tags: android, image-processing

In my app i want to edit images like brightness, contrast, etc. I got some tutorial and i am trying this to change contrast

```
public static Bitmap createContrast(Bitmap src, double value) {
        // image size
        int width = src.getWidth();
        int height = src.getHeight();
        // create output bitmap
        Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, src.getConfig());
        // color information
        int A, R, G, B;
        int pixel;
        // get contrast value
        double contrast = Math.pow((100 + value) / 100, 2);

        // scan through all pixels
        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                // get pixel color
                pixel = src.getPixel(x, y);
                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                // apply filter contrast for every channel R, G, B
                R = Color.red(pixel);
                R = (int)(((((R / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
                if(R < 0) { R = 0; }
                else if(R > 255) { R = 255; }

                G = Color.red(pixel);
                G = (int)(((((G / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
                if(G < 0) { G = 0; }
                else if(G > 255) { G = 255; }

                B = Color.red(pixel);
                B = (int)(((((B / 255.0) - 0.5) * contrast) + 0.5) * 255.0);
                if(B < 0) { B = 0; }
                else if(B > 255) { B = 255; }

                // set new pixel color to output bitmap
                bmOut.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));

            }
        }


        // return final image
        return bmOut;
```

calling it as :

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)(findViewById(R.id.image));
        //image.setImageBitmap(createContrast(bitmap));
```

But i dont see any offect happening for the image. Can you please help where i am going wrong.

I saw the effectFactory from APi 14 . IS there something similar / any tutorial that can be used for older versions for image processing

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic problems with this approach. The first two are coding issues. First, you are always calling `Color.red`, and there is no `Color.green` and `Color.blue` to be found in your code. The second issue is that this calculation is too repetitive. You assume the colors are in the range [0, 255], so it is much faster to create a array of 256 positions with the contrast calculated for each `i` in [0, 255].

The third issue is more problematic. Why did you consider this algorithm to improve contrast ? The results are meaningless for RGB, you might get something better in a different color system. Here are the results you should expect, with your parameter `value` at 0, 10, 20, and 30:

[image] [image] [image] [image]

And here is a sample Python code to perform the operation:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
width, height = img.size

cvalue = float(sys.argv[2]) # Your parameter "value".
contrast = ((100 + cvalue) / 100) ** 2

def apply_contrast(c):
    c = (((c / 255.) - 0.5) * contrast + 0.5) * 255.0
    return min(255, max(0, int(c)))

# Build the lookup table.
ltu = []
for i in range(256):
    ltu.append(apply_contrast(i))

# The following "point" method applies a function to each
# value in the image. It considers the image as a flat sequence
# of values.
img = img.point(lambda x: ltu[x])

img.save(sys.argv[3])
```